# Weird Results in C++

Tags: c++

I have good experience in Python and very little in C++. I'm trying to write a program to print each element of the 'sales' array:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
void printArray(int, int);

int main()
{
    char chips[5][50] = {"mild", "medium", "sweet", "hot", "zesty"};
    int sales[5][6] = {0};

    int tempSales, counter;
    const int i = 5;

    for (counter = 0; counter < i; counter++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter in the sales for " << chips[counter] << ": ";
        cin >> tempSales;

        tempSales >> sales[counter][5];
    }

    cout << "{";
    for (int counter = 0; counter < i; counter++)
    {
        cout << chips[counter] << ", ";
    }
    cout << "}" << endl;

    cout << "{";
    for (int counter = 0; counter < i; counter++)
    {
        cout << sales[counter] << ", ";
    }
    cout << "}" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

To solve this problem, I need to have the same commands and keywords I still have, and it can't be any advanced or weird syntax. What's going on? I'm getting results like:

```
{mild, medium, sweet, hot, zesty, }
{010FF6F4, 010FF70C, 010FF724, 010FF73C, 010FF754, }
```

Whereas I just want to see 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5 for the second array. Please help!

Comment: Why do you have sales as a 2d array if you are only storing one value per row?  `int sales[5]{};` will work fine for you, you just need to adjust your code accordingly so it compiles.

Comment: *I have good experience in Python and very little in C++* -- Bottom line -- Do **not** use other languages as a guide or as a model in writing and learning C++.  It will either lead to code that compiles and does things different than expected, or compiler errors you can't figure out because the code looks "right", bugs, or just plain old weird looking C++ code.

Comment: I recommend against using raw arrays, buffers, and c-strings in C++, unless absolutely necessary (systems work or critical for performance). `std::vector<std::string>` and `std::vector<int>` would make this work much more easily.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a two dimensional array with `sales[][]` but then try to read from it like from a one dimensional one. Instead just declare it with `int sales[5]{}` and save your input with

```
tempSales >> sales[counter];
```

Answer (score 1):

Also the assignment into chips and sales won't repeat the initialization pattern.